# Delete regex java filex

Tags: java, regex, batch-file

I want to delete a command from my java project with sed on all my java files using regex.

The line that i'm trying to delete start with Logger.log and ends with Logger.DEBUG. it looks something like this:

```
Logger.log("this is an test", Logger.DEBUG);
```

Sometimes this log can be very be (3 or 4 lines so I need to think on way to cover this as well).

My current Regex is:

```
/Logger.log(.*)[\n(*)](.*)Logger.DEBUG(.*);/g
```

All my java files are available in 1 package.

I tried the SED command without no luck:

```
sed -r -i '/Logger.log(.*)[\n(*)](.*)Logger.DEBUG(.*);/g' *.java
```

How can I move on all files and delete this line?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `find` and `sed` to achieve this.

To find all `*.java` files in a folder (remove `-maxdepth 1` if you want the sear to be recursive):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.java"
```

To remove line:

```
sed -ri /^Logger\.log.*?Logger\.DEBUG\.*?\;/d
```

**Combined:**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.java" -exec sed -ri /^Logger\.log.*?Logger\.DEBUG\.*?\;/d {} \;
```